# Installing openPLC runtime doesn't work using Cygwin, wget not found (?)

Tags: plc

I was installing openPLC runtime using installer and apparently it doesn't work for me, so i installed manually and ended up stuck in this proccess [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm5dV.png)

I don't know what is wrong since i have installed openPLC editor

I hope that i can run my openPLC runtime using cygwim terminal so yeah please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already working, so I think my problem is I don't download the driver for my hardware using libUSB. thanks